# How to initiate click to activate code in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am designing a shooting game in Unity 3d for which I have a requirement that only when an image is tapped the shooting should occur. Please check the command used for the purpose:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            if (!clickedConfirmed){
                GameObjectClicked = GetClickedGameObject();
                clickedConfirmed = true;

            }
```

Currently, shooting occurs when clicked anywhere on the screen. How can activation of shooting be bonded only to the gameobject (image) instead of being activated when clicked anywhere on the screen.

Comment: Can't you just use `OnMouseDown()` function instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your need to give more context in your example, *especially* what `GetClickedGameObject()` is actually doing internally.

As such I'm limited in what I can say is the problem, but I suspect that you aren't using `GameObjectClicked` correctly.

I would expect that you'd do a check such as:

```
this.gameObject == GameObjectClicked
```

Note that if this being used as a method of developing a UI there are more elegant solutions out there, including the long awaited new GUI system included in the [Unity3d 4.6 open beta](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta/4.6).